# R: function for home inventory count?

Tags: r

I have a list of homes sales data in my neighborhood listed as

```
address, listingdate, saledate
101 Street, 2017/01/01, 2017/06/06
106 Street, 2017/03/01, 2017/08/11
102 Street, 2017/05/04, 2017/06/13
109 Street, 2017/07/04, 2017/11/24
...
```

I would like to calculate the number of homes listed for sale (and not sold) at the listing date too see how home sales and listing vary throughout the year.

in the example:

```
address,    listingdate, saledate, inventory
101 Street, 2017/01/01, 2017/06/06, 1
106 Street, 2017/03/01, 2017/08/11, 2
102 Street, 2017/05/04, 2017/06/13, 3
109 Street, 2017/07/04, 2017/11/24, 2
...
```

E.g. 109 Street was listed when only 106 and 109 Street were for sale.

Is there a simple 1-step R expression that can calculate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is 3 simple steps. I'll just set the bar, I'm sure someone else will be able to go under it.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
dt <- data.table(
  address = paste(c(101,106,102,109),"Street"),
  listing_date = ymd(c('2017/01/01','2017/03/01','2017/05/04','2017/07/04')),
  saledate = ymd(c("2017/06/06","2017/08/11","2017/06/13","2017/11/24")),
  key = 'listing_date'))

dt2 <- rbind(dt[,.(date = listing_date, x = 1)], dt[,.(date = saledate, x = -1)])
dt3 <- dt2[, .(x = sum(x)), keyby = date][, .(date, inventory = cumsum(x))]
dt[, inventory := dt3[dt, on=c('date' = 'listing_date'), inventory]]
```

Or instead as a one-liner

```
dt[,inventory:=dt[,.(d=listing_date:saledate),.(address)][,.N,key=d][dt,N]]
dt[]
#>       address listing_date   saledate inventory
#> 1: 101 Street   2017-01-01 2017-06-06         1
#> 2: 106 Street   2017-03-01 2017-08-11         2
#> 3: 102 Street   2017-05-04 2017-06-13         3
#> 4: 109 Street   2017-07-04 2017-11-24         2
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't use the specific solution because of incompatibilities between data.table and tibbles, but the general algorithm was very enlightening. I could translate the general idea to tidyverse land with a couple of changes

```
# import data from data file

homesale_file = "Home sales data.csv"
homesales <- read_csv(homesale_file, 
        col_types = cols(listingdate = col_date(format = "%m/%d/%Y"), 
                         saledate = col_date(format = "%m/%d/%Y")
                         )
                    )

#
# calculation for inventory
#

listingdate <- tibble(address=homesales$address, listingdate=homesales$listingdate, type="listing",y=1)
saledate <- tibble(address=homesales$address, listingdate=homesales$saledate, type="sale", y=-1)
summation = bind_rows(listingdate, saledate) %>% arrange(listingdate) %>% mutate(inventory=cumsum(y)) %>% select(-y) %>% filter(type=="listing")
homesales <- homesales %>% inner_join(summation) %>% select(-type)
```

@pseudopin, thanks for the help!